# Case expression for date format conversion

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an `Entrydate` column that comes from Source in below date formats

1. YYYY-MM-DD HH.MM.SS
2. YYYY-MM-DD

It is loaded to a table as `YYYYMM` format. I am looking for a case expression that handles both the conditions.

I am using the below SQL

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN to_char(ENTRYDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH.MM.SS') 
          THEN to_char(ENTRYDATE, 'YYYYMM')
       to_char(ENTRYDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
          THEN to_char(ENTRYDATE, 'YYYYMM')
FROM 
    TABLE;
```

but I get this error:

> ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

I will need to get the date in YYYYMM format to validate the output table.

Comment: What is the data type of `EntryDate`?  The usage suggests that it is a string.

Comment: Dates don't have a format, you're either storing them as strings (bad) or they're being displayed as strings in a particular format by your client; but then referring to two different formats wouldn't really make sense. It would help to show the table structure (both the source and the target if this is actually part of an insert) along with sample data and expected results - all as formatted text.

Comment: Why are you loading the date as a number into the table? That is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting `invalid relational operator` is that the function `TO_CHAR()` does not return a Boolean value.

My guess is that you have what are ostensibly date values stored as `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`, and you need to convert to a certain format. If they're stored as `DATE` values then you should not have much to do. But assuming `CHAR`/`VARCHAR`/`VARCHAR2`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(entrydate, '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}( \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})$')
         THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(entrydate, '^(\d{4})-(\d{2}).*$', '\1\2')
       END AS yyyymm_date
  FROM table;
```

(Note that you were also missing an `END` from your `CASE` statement.)

The above will return a `NULL` if the value of `entrydate` is in some other format.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why a `case`?  If you have two different formats, then the value is presumably already a string.  So:

```
select replace(substr(ENTRYDATE, 7), '-', '')
```

If it were a `date` column, then you would just do:

```
select to_char(ENTRYDATE, 'YYYYMM')
```

Comment: I am using CASE since I have to perform few more transformations for other fields. Yes, it is a Date format. However the target table format is "number(6,0)".  When I use to_char, I get "Data type mismatch".

Comment: @Raja, Why on earth do you plan to store date values as NUMBER?

Comment: Is the first query supposed to have `substr(ENTRYDATE, 1, 7)` ?

Comment: @All, thanks for your Inputs,  I used the to_char function to get the result. On the output table, I was able to do a Cast function to match my results.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - I do not have control of the DB design :)

Comment: @Raja : You wrote "Yes, it is a Date format". If you are using `DATE` type, then there's no sense in detecting format (as this is not something stored in the DB). If you are saying, that this data are dates in that specific format, then it's a string type (e.g. `VARCHAR2`), so the answer to @GordonLinoff should probably be "No, it's not a date column.".

Comment: @Raja I'm afraid *'Yes, it is a Date format'* doesn't tell us anything. We can already see there is a date **format** being used. What we don't know is the underlying **datatype** that `entrydate` is defined with. In Oracle, `date` is a separate datatype from `varchar2`, `number` etc, so different handling will be required depending on what it is.